# Issue with next.js containers overflowing when their content adjusts to @media rules

Tags: css, flexbox, next.js, responsive

I've been pulling my hair for 2 days now trying to fix an issue with next.js
It's my first project on it, and I believe I'm missing something.

What happens is basically, I have 3 layers (refer to the 3D View from the edge just below) that don't want to go under a certain width (1040px)
All the content inside of it DOES resize correctly, but I end up having a huge overflow, and the horizontal scroll of course.
[Screenshot of the 3DView showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nifOr.png)

I tried putting @media rules on these layers, but they don't seem to apply.
When I try to make these divs/layers be `{display: flex}` it completely bugs the rest of the website.

I will include the code for the index.js, the header and the content are not the issues.

**index.js**

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
   <>  
   <main className={containerStyles.container}>
   <Head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </Head>
  <div className={containerStyles.column}>
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <ul>
      <div className={styles.wrapListItem}><Link href="../buy"><li className={styles.listItem}>   <p>Buy </p>       </li></Link></div>
      <div className={styles.wrapListItem}><Link href="../doc"><li className={styles.listItem}>   <p>Documentation</p>        </li></Link></div>
      <div className={styles.wrapListItem}><Link href="../tos"><li className={styles.listItem}>   <p>TOS</p>                  </li></Link></div>
      <div className={styles.wrapListItem}><Link href="../cart"><li className={styles.listItem}>  <p>Cart</p>                 </li></Link></div>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  </>
  )
  }

export default Home;
```

**global.css**

```
    @import 'Fontfaces.css';
        html,
        body {
          cursor: url("../public/2x/cursor@2x.png"), auto;
          background-color: black;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
            Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
          min-width: 1040px;
          z-index: 0;
          
        }
        a {
          color: inherit;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        :root{
          --brand-yellow: rgb(255, 217, 0);
        }
        a:active{
          color: var(--brand-yellow);
        }
        .glowing{
          color: #ffef2a;
          font-size: 20px;
          -webkit-animation: glow 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          -moz-animation: glow 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: glow 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
        }
        @media(max-width:1040px){
          body{
            max-width: @media(max-width:1040px){
      body{
        max-width: 100vw;
      }
    };
      }
    }
```

**ContainerStyles.module.css**

```
    .container{
    min-height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: black;
}
.column{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media(max-width:1040px){
    .container{
        transition: 1s;
        flex-direction: column;
        max-width: 100vw;
        margin-right: 0px;
        
    }
    .column{
        transition: 1s;
        background-color: red;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100vw;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

sorry for the janky formatting on that one, first time posting on StackOverflow

Here is another screenshot of what it looks like in a browser.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lf8b.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!
PS: The 1s transitions and the horrible colors are only here for debugging, no judging please xoxo

Comment: Would be useful to know what `styles.main` and `styles.wrapListItem` are. Could you maybe create this example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). They have a NextJS template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a friend with more experience told me that adding
`overflow-x: hidden` to my @media rules for the body is a normal thing to do, and it was indeed what I had to do!